# How to set terminal current input from bash scripts

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

My bash script simplifies producing some long terminal command, for example

```
git diff "file.one" "file.two" "file.million"
```

After that I want this builded command not to run from inside the script but to set it to terminal input, so user can press "Enter" and run it. This I will achieve following:

1. User can edit command before run it
2. Command will be in history

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do something similar is to push an item into the history:

```
history -s 'command to store'
```

Following this, the user would have to press <kbd>↑</kbd> to go back to the command and edit/execute it.

**Note:** If you do this, the script must be *sourced* not *executed*, i.e. the user would have to run `. /path/to/script.sh` instead of just `/path/to/script.sh`.

---

To let the user edit a command before executing it in a script, you could something like:

```
command='git diff "file.one" …'
read -e -i "$command" command
eval "$command"
```

The `-e` option uses readline so that filename completion works and the `-i` option pre-populates the input field with the supplied text.

You can optionally do `history -s "$command"` afterwards (again, the script would have to be *source*d for this to work).